# Python code to reiterate different files

Tags: python

I have written Python code to rearrange some files in a directory, create new directories and delete old ones to form the dataset in the structure that I want it.  Previously, I was doing this with repetative code because it got the job done but I want to clean it up and see no reason to repeat code.

```
test_names_path = 'food-101/meta/test.txt'
train_names_path = 'food-101/meta/train.txt'
train = 'food-101/images/train'
test = 'food-101/images/test'

def assemble_dataset(data_path, folder):
  for line in data_path:
    name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
    name_of_file = line.split
    Path('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename(folder + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')

  if data_path == 'food-101/meta/train.txt':
    with open('food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
      for element in train_file:
        name_of_folder = element.split('/')[0]
        if os.path.exists('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder):
          shutil.rmtree('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder)

# with open('food-101/meta/test.txt') as test_file:
#   for line in test_file:
#     name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
#     name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
#     Path('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('food-101/images/test/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')

# # Moves all training images to the Food-101/images directory and renames them
# with open('food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
#   for line in train_file:
#     name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
#     name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
#     Path('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('food-101/images/train/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')

# Removes empty directories inside Food-101/images
# with open('food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
#   for folder in train_file:
#     name_of_folder = folder.split('/')[0]
#     if os.path.exists('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder):
#       shutil.rmtree('food-101/images/' + name_of_folder)

assemble_dataset(train_names_path, train)
assemble_dataset(test_names_path, test)
```

The commented out code is the old code and is what I'm trying to shrink.  In `def assemble_dataset()`, the first 2 blocks of code correspond to the first 2 `with open()` chunks. The following `if data_path...` statement corresponds to the last `with open()` chunk.

Below is the original code:

```
git_repo_tags = ['AB', 'C', 'DEF', 'G', 'HILMNO', 'PR', 'STW', 'X']

# Cloning the github repositories
for repo in git_repo_tags:
  git.Git('.').clone('git://github.com/utility-repos/' + repo)

  #Removing the .git folder from each repo
  shutil.rmtree(repo + '/.git')

# Creating the Food-101/images directory and subdirectory if it doesn't already exist
if not os.path.exists('Food-101/images/train') and not os.path.exists('Food-101/images/test'):
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images/train')
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images/test')

    # Going through the repo X and moving everything a branch up
    for i in os.listdir('X'):
      shutil.move(os.path.join('X', i), 'Food-101')

    # Going through the other repos and moving everything to Food-101/images
    for directory in git_repo_tags:
      for subdirectory in os.listdir(directory):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, subdirectory), 'Food-101/images')

with open('Food-101/meta/test.txt') as test_file:
  for line in test_file:
    name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
    name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
    Path('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('Food-101/images/test/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')

# Moves all training images to the Food-101/images directory and renames them
with open('Food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
  for line in train_file:
    name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
    name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
    Path('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('Food-101/images/train/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')

# Removes empty directories inside Food-101/images
with open('Food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
  for folder in train_file:
    name_of_folder = folder.split('/')[0]
    if os.path.exists('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder):
      shutil.rmtree('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder)

# Removes empty directories 
for dirs in git_repo_tags:
  shutil.rmtree(dirs)
```

Comment: Please post the code that you want review unmodified. We're not going to unpick which lines are comments and which lines are code before reviewing it.

Comment: @l0b0 Done... :)

Comment: You would do well simply to read through [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Also `for line in datapath` will iterate characters in string as you have not `open()`ed the file.

Answer (score 4):

As @David says, extensive replacement of your `os` and `shutil` calls with `pathlib` will get you 90% of the way to a better solution. The one exception is `shutil.rmtree` which does not have a `pathlib` equivalent.

I'll go through most of the instances.

### Immutable constants

```
git_repo_tags = ['AB', 'C', 'DEF', 'G', 'HILMNO', 'PR', 'STW', 'X']
```

should be

```
GIT_REPO_TAGS = ('AB', 'C', 'DEF', 'G', 'HILMNO', 'PR', 'STW', 'X')
```

since it's global and you don't intend on changing it.

### Exists

```
if not os.path.exists('Food-101/images/train') and not os.path.exists('Food-101/images/test'):
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images/train')
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images/test')
    ...
```

can be

```
images = Path('Food-101/images')
train = images / 'train'
test = images / 'test'
if not (train.exists() or test.exists()):
    train.mkdir()
    test.mkdir()
    ...
```

### Move

```
for i in os.listdir('X'):
  shutil.move(os.path.join('X', i), 'Food-101')
```

can be

```
food = Path('Food-101')
repo = Path('X')
for i in repo.iterdir():
    i.rename(food / i.name)
```

### Path appends

```
Path('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg')
```

should be

```
(Path('Food-101/images') / name_of_folder / name_of_file).with_suffix('.jpg')
```